# My app is not showing any reviews and ratings on the App Store?

Tags: iphone, ios, app-store-connect, itunes-app

My app has been on the App Store for 48 hours and I have had several people download and give a rating and review. For some reason the ratings and review are not showing up in the App Store. I was wondering if it's something I did on my end and how do I fix this?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You cant do anything to prevent the reviews or rating to show up in the app store. If it was possible, a lot of scam apps would have done that. So just sit back and relax. Following information may be helpful.

1. You need minimum 5 ratings to display an average rating in appstore
2. Each appstore handles reviews/ratings separately. That means at least five users from the same appstore (Eg: US) should rate it before the average rating shows up.
3. App reviews and ratings are not updated in real time.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I thought I had done something wrong on my end.

Answer (score 8):

Go to [iTunes Connect](http://itunesconnect.apple.com) > Manage Applications > select your app > select current version > go to Customer Reviews and you will se a dropdown with all the countries where your app is available.

Selecting a country should show you all reviews in that country even if they have not appeared on the AppStore itself yet.

Comment: I can see all the reviews in the ITunes Connect but they are showing for app in the App Store.